# run time error when embedding monaco editor in ember app

Tags: ember.js, monaco-editor, ember-octane

I am trying to use [monaco-editor](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor) in my ember app, 
I am using
[ember-monaco](https://github.com/mike-north/ember-monaco) for that. 
I followed the [instructions](https://github.com/mike-north/ember-monaco#usage) and added in my `application.hbs` the following code:

```
{{code-editor
  language="typescript"
  code=sample1
  onChange=(action (mut sample1))
  theme="light"
  onReady=(action editorReady)
}}
```

I am running the app, but the editor doesn't appear,
I get the following runtime error:

```
index.js:181 Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Action passed is null or undefined in (action) from (generated application controller).
at assert (index.js:181:1)
at makeClosureAction (index.js:738:1)
at makeDynamicClosureAction (index.js:727:1)
at index.js:679:1
at Object.evaluate (runtime.js:2084:1)
at AppendOpcodes.evaluate (runtime.js:1312:1)
at LowLevelVM.evaluateSyscall (runtime.js:5232:1)
at LowLevelVM.evaluateInner (runtime.js:5188:1)
at LowLevelVM.evaluateOuter (runtime.js:5180:1)
at VM.next (runtime.js:6191:1)
```

I removed the actions

```
{{code-editor
  language="typescript"
  code=sample1
  theme="light"
}}
```

Now the editor appears but with out the sample code (since I deleted the relevant lines), 
What is the correct syntax?

Ember version:

```
ember-cli: 3.28.5
node: 10.24.1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `ember-source@3.16+`, it's recommend to directly reference actions / functions, like:

```
{{code-editor
  language="typescript"
  code=this.sample1
  onChange=this.handleChange
  theme="light"
  onReady=this.editorReady
}}
```

(assuming handleChange and editorReady are defined your backing class) (also assuming you have a backing class)